# How do I plot a 3D-block in matplotlib/python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

Im trying to plot a 3D-Block similar to this: [example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRMnJ.png)

On the reference picture we have block in every possible place (in every mesh node). They're pretty opaque, but their colors and sizes correspond to their values.

How can I plot blocks and control their size to achieve a result that looks like the example?

I've tried different things:

1. Basic scatter with transparency and cmap
2. Voxel plotting

Im not very satisfied with my results which don't look as informative as the sample I've shared.